# Why is groovy not finding my variable in its scope

Tags: groovy, scope, static

I get this error:

```
Apparent variable 'b' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes:
You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from a static context.
You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelling.
You attempted to use a method 'b' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by the grammar.
 @ line 11, column 12.
        int a = (b + 5);
              ^
```

Why isn't it recognizing b as a variable? I'm trying to test how scoping works in Groovy. Is it static or dynamic?

```
class practice{
        static void main(String[] args)
        {       int b=5;
                foo(); // returns 10
                bar(); // returns 10
                println('Hello World');
        }
        //public int b = 5;
        static void foo()
        {
                int a = (b + 5);
                println(a);
        }

         static void bar()
        {
                int b = 2;
                println(foo());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two local variables called b, one in main and one in bar. The foo method can't see either of them. If groovy used dynamic scoping then it would see the value of b in bar and use it in foo, that that doesn't happen indicates scoping is static.

It looks like the code posted came from [here](https://msujaws.wordpress.com/2011/05/03/static-vs-dynamic-scoping). Here's how I'd translate it to Groovy:

```
public class ScopeExample {
    int b = 5
    int foo() {
        int a = b + 5
        a
    }
    int bar() {
        int b = 2
        foo()
    }
    static void main(String ... args) {
        def x = new ScopeExample()
        println x.foo()
        println x.bar()
    }
}
```

Running main prints

```
10
10
```

showing that the local variable before the call doesn't change the result.

Scoping in groovy is lexical (meaning static), not dynamic. Groovy, Java, Scheme, Python, and JavaScript (among lots of others) are all lexically scoped. With lexical scoping the context in which code is defined decides what is in scope, not the context at runtime when it is executed. Figuring out what is bound with dynamic scoping requires knowing the call tree.